Localization in the "hypercube"
In paper Many-Body Localization and Thermalization in Quantum Statistical Mechanics it has the following statement:

The many-body pure-state space of the full system of N spins is the outer product of the pure-state spaces of each spin. A convenient (and conventional) basis set for this space is the $2^N$ simultaneous eigenstates of all of the $\{\sigma_i^z\}$. This basis set has a geometry: It can be represented as the $2^N$ corners of an $N$-dimensional hypercube. Nearest-neighbor points on this hypercube are states that differ by flipping only one spin. Each axis of the hypercube represents one spin, so in general this hypercube does not have any rotational symmetry because each of its axes represents a different point in real space. The Hamiltonian of the many-body system can be represented as a single quantum particle hopping on this hypercube, with only short-range hopping. But a many-body state that is localized need not appear localized on this hypercube: For example, a many-spin product pure state that is localized so each spin points in its own particular direction on its own Bloch sphere, with the directions selected randomly and uniformly on the Bloch spheres, appears quite extended when represented on this hypercube. Such a state only looks localized on the hypercube if the basis choice for each spin corresponds to the state in which that spin is localized. Note that the geometry of this hypercube is not the geometry of the space (the Hilbert space) of the full system’s pure states. The latter space is a $2^N$-dimensional complex vector space, and each of its $2^N$ axes is one of the corners of this hypercube. Thus, our system has at least three spaces that can be considered: real space, the hypercube of many-body basis states, and the Hilbert space.

I wonder:

What is the "hypercube" like, i.e., for a general state, and how to represent it on such hypercube?
What does "localization" mean on the hypercube? What does "extend" mean in the above statement?


The first part is probably just a reference to a hypercube graph see wikipedia entry. If we have vertices labelled by the set of $n$-bit strings, and add an edge wherever two strings differ by only 1 bit, then the resulting graph looks like a hypercube in $n$ dimensions. In this case, we just label the vertices with computational basis states.
